# Datagridview edit/save button

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` table displaying some customer information from an SQL table. I have added a `datagridviewbuttoncolumn` on the end to allow editing of a single row at a time. However, I cannot even get basic functionality to work with the button. The `UseColumnTextForButton` property doesn't seem to work, nor when I progrommatically try to change the text.

```
private void CardList_grdvw_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = false;
            var btn = (DataGridViewButtonCell)senderGrid.CurrentCell;
            btn.Value = "save";
        }
    }
```

I have checked to verify that the correct cell is being referenced. When debugging, after I set `btn.Value = "save"` it still is `null`.

Additionally, the row is still un-editable even after setting its `ReadOnly` property to `false`.

[Datagridview wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oym6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Text property of a column in the DataGridView is blank.  I *think* you are confusing the HeaderText and Text properties.  When you set the UseColumnTextForButton to true, the buttons will use the Text property of the column.

Make sure you supply that Text property in the designer.

To make the code you posted work, set the UseColumnTextForButton back to false.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I did have that confused. Do you have any idea why I am still unable to edit the row after I set the `ReadOnly` property to `false`?

Comment: @AlexEstrada Your code worked for me when I have it false and I click on the button.

Comment: So, I must have something somewhere else preventing it? Would previously setting the whole grid to `Readonly` or not checking `Enable Editing` in the designer affect it?

Comment: ReadOnly doesn't affect it.  I don't know what "Enable Editing" means.  If the whole grid is disabled then no, nothing happens.  Make sure this event is wired up.